# reading parameter from .properties file to .xml file

Tags: xml, spring, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a application.xml file (directory = WEB-INF/application.xml)

and I have a jasperserver.properties file (directory = WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver.properties)

This is in the jasperserver.properties file

```
SERVICE_URL=http://b-reptest-lnx.nwu.ac.za:8026/jasperserver-pro/j_spring_cas_security
```

I want to read that "SERVICE_URL" property from the application.xml file

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 6):

use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` in application.xml.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>classpath:path/to/jasperserver.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

to load properties file.
Then use ${SERVICE_URL} in your application.xml to substitute values:

```
<bean class="your class">
  <property name="serviceURL"><value>${SERVICE_URL}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: do I need to enter the full path name ? I can't use the server name or port etc. else the code wont be generic as these values constantly change (file is in Servername:Port\webapps\jasperserver-pro\WEB-INF\internal\jasperserver-pro.properties)

Comment: no, I think `classpath:internal/jasperserver.properties` or `classpath:WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver.properties` will be fine

Comment: I get java.io.FileNotFoundException error with those. I tried numorous other paths & double checks everything, no luck :(

Comment: Try `classpath:jasperserver-pro.prope‌​rties`. Are you sure your file is deployed?

Comment: I used value="../WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver-pro.properties" and got it to work now I get Could not resolve placeholder'SERVICE_URL' error

Comment: This path is really strange: usually object in class path under WEB-INF/ are loaded using `classpath:filename`... add stacktrace. Do you check if your deployed properties file contains the property?

Comment: Yes I checked it contains the property, classpath:WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver.properties seems to find the file but again not property. perhaps its finding the wrong file

Comment: The only way is to debug `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and check if it loading file and properties

Answer (score 1):

I think your jasperserver.properties is not in your classpath.

remove classpath given in value tag in bean definition , below is the modified

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>/WEB-INF/internal/jasperserver.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Then try it

Other wise copy jasperserver.properties to src folder and add modified bean below mentioned

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="location">
    <value>classpath:jasperserver.properties</value>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Hope it will help.